# Prevent Lockscreen / Notificationcenter from swiping down in react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Starting with iOS 11 the behavior to prioritize own gestures over the system gestures on screen edges changed.

Previously iOS assumed that if you hide the status bar you want your gestures on screen edges to be fired first.

Now you have to override the `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` method to achieve the same result as explained here: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/avoiding-conflicts-with-system-gestures-at-screen-edges/.

How can we do that in react-native? Is this already dealt with in a recent version or not? I can't find any reference to that method in the react-native source code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by swapping the `UIViewController` being used to one that implements `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` in the way that you like.

Start by creating a new class, e.g. `MainViewController`, that returns the desired value:

```
//
//  MainViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and:

```
//
//  MainViewController.m
//

#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (UIRectEdge)preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures
{
  return UIRectEdgeBottom;
}

@end
```

Finally, swap the generic view controller for the specialized one that we just created:

```
  */

 #import "AppDelegate.h"
+#import "MainViewController.h"

 #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
 #import <React/RCTRootView.h>

===== SNIP =====

   rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
-  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
+  UIViewController *rootViewController = [MainViewController new];
   rootViewController.view = rootView;
   self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue using methods swizzle using a **Swift** **extension** on `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {
fileprivate static func swizzleReduceSystemGestures() {
      guard let aClass = NSClassFromString("RNNNavigationController") ?? NSClassFromString("RNNStackController"), // aClass?.alloc() as? UINavigationController
      let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, #selector(getter: UIViewController.preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures)),
      let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, #selector(getter: preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGesturesSwizzled)) else { return }
      method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
  }

  @objc public var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGesturesSwizzled: UIRectEdge {
       return .all
  }
}
```

Then call this static method in your `AppDelegate`:

```
 UIViewController.swizzleReduceSystemGestures()
```

Similarly you can set `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` with swizzle and it works like a charm until they give us a proper solution.